# Acceder una sola tabla con web scraping y python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, scraping

estoy intentando scrapear una web de estadisticas con python para la creacion de gráficas, principalmente, pero no puedo acceder a una sola tabla. La página es la siguiente: https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html#all_team-stats-base

Solo quiero acceder a  una tabla, que es la quinta, la titulada como "Team Per Game Stats", pero me es imposible, he probado a acceder mediante la id de la pagina pero nada. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

URL = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html'
pagina = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

#response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagina, 'html.parser')
tabla = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'team-stats-per_game'})

print(tabla)

#Devuelve None
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La página en cuestión hace algo curioso, la tabla que buscas aparece comentada en el HTML original (view-source:https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html), entiendo que lo que hace es descomentarla por javascript, de todas formas puedes acceder a ella, jugando un poco con las cadenas:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

URL = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html'
pagina = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(pagina, 'html.parser')

# Buscamos el contenedor de la tabla    
conteneder_tabla = tabla = soup.find('div', {'id': 'all_team-stats-per_game'})

str_tabla = str(conteneder_tabla)
# nos quedamos ocn el "outputHTML" de la tabla
str_tabla = str_tabla[str_tabla.index('<table') : (str_tabla.rindex('</table>') + 8)]

soup = BeautifulSoup(str_tabla, 'html.parser')

tabla = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'team-stats-per_game'})

print(tabla)
```